# Highcharts add an image to that chart with an onClick event attached to it

Tags: highcharts

I have created a chart where I've added an image. 
Now when I click this image I want to set the yAxis max to a specific point, and when I click it again to reset the yAxis to the original values.
This is the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/inadcod/TynwP/
I have managed to add the image, to add a click event to the image, but it's as far as I got.
Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks!

Comment: I think your question isn't what's on the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do what you want.

**First way**:

The problem is that it's not possible to update chart options and then `redraw` to get it updated, you have to `destroy` and then create it again like the following.

So, for this you can store your chart `options` into a var and then pass as parameter.

```
// inside options
    load: function() {
        this.renderer.image('http://inadcod.com/img/zoom.png', 70, 10, 28, 28)
        .on('click', function() {
            if(options.yAxis.max) {
                delete options.yAxis.max; // return to default
            } else {
                options.yAxis.max = 25;
            }
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);                        
        })
        .css({
            cursor: 'pointer',
            position: 'relative',
            "margin-left": "-90px",
            opacity: 0.75
        }).attr({
            id: 'myImage',
            zIndex: -100
        }).add();
    }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TynwP/9/)

**Second way**:
`redraw` isn't called if you just update `axis` data like the following.
`chart.yAxis[0].max = 25;`, that's why I suggested the way above.
But if you set `chart.yAxis[0].isDisty = true;` and call `chart.redraw();`, it will work. You can see my demo bellow.

```
// inside chart options
    load: function() {
        this.renderer.image('http://inadcod.com/img/zoom.png', 70, 10, 28, 28)
        .on('click', function() {
            var axis = chart.yAxis[0];
            axis.max = 25;
            axis.isDirty = true;
            chart.redraw();
        })
        .css({
            cursor: 'pointer',
            position: 'relative',
            "margin-left": "-90px",
            opacity: 0.75
        }).attr({
            id: 'myImage', // your image id
            zIndex: -100
        }).add();
    }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TynwP/8/)